# HDF5 rename header field

Tags: hdf5

I have some HDF5 files those header fields are less than explicit. So, I would like to edit those to replace them with something else. For example, using `h5dump --header file.h5` I get this:

```
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "log" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
         H5T_COMPOUND {
            H5T_STD_U32LE "sec";
            H5T_STD_U32LE "usec";
         } "time";
         H5T_IEEE_F32LE "ook";
         ...
```

In this instance, I want to rename "ook" to "eek" -- say, this is a silly example.

*How can I do it?*

Comment: I am not adverse to using [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/) for example. In fact, that would be the ideal answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible as it is forbidden by the specification.